# Google Play Billing : Determine a pending price change

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-billing

I am currently looking into how to deal with price change.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#price-change-communicate) suggests communicating with the user when application starts.
To start the price change confirmation flow, the documentation indicates the application *can determine if the user has a pending price change by looking at the priceChange field in the [subscription resource](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions).* (available through a REST API) *If present, this field indicates the subscription has a price change, and the priceChange.state field indicates whether the price change has been accepted or is still outstanding.*

Is there any corresponding Google Play Billing Library API that would provide the same information?

Comment: The same question is raised on Google play billing sample lib https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/180

Comment: @DharmendraPratapSingh Thank you for pointing to the older question, I will close this one, and update other question and github issue.